# Angular Error: Unknown provider: dataserviceProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to inject two factories and my code is getting the error "Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: dataserviceProvider:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">......
```

This is the html page:

```
@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/App/Controllers/HomeController.js"></script>
    <script src="~/App/Factories/dataservice.js"></script>
    <script src="~/App/Factories/quizMetrics.js"></script>
    <script src="~/App/Controllers/list.js"></script>
    <script src="~/App/Controllers/quiz.js"></script>
    <script src="~/App/Controllers/results.js"></script>
}


<div ng-controller="HomeController as ctrl" class="md-content" ng-cloak>....   </div>
```

And I am trying to inject here and if I remove quizMetrics, DataService everithing is working fine:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])
    .controller('HomeController', HomeController);

    HomeController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$filter', '$mdDialog', '$timeout', 'quiz','list','result','quizMetrics', 'dataservice' ];

    function HomeController($scope, $http, $filter, $mdDialog, $timeout, quiz,list,result,quizMetrics, dataservice ) {
})();
```

And one of my scripts:

```
(function(){

angular.module("MyApp")
    .factory("quizMetrics", QuizMetrics);

    QuizMetrics.$inject = ['DataService'];

    function QuizMetrics(DataService){

        var quizObj = {
            quizActive: false,
            resultsActive: false,
            changeState: changeState, // changeState is a named function below
            correctAnswers: [],
            markQuiz: markQuiz, // markQuiz is a named function below
            numCorrect: 0
        };
        return quizObj;

        function changeState(metric, state){
            if(metric === "quiz"){
                quizObj.quizActive = state;
            }else if(metric === "results"){
                quizObj.resultsActive = state;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }

        function markQuiz(){
            quizObj.correctAnswers = DataService.correctAnswers;
            for(var i = 0; i < DataService.quizQuestions.length; i++){
                if(DataService.quizQuestions[i].selected === DataService.correctAnswers[i]){
                    DataService.quizQuestions[i].correct = true;
                    quizObj.numCorrect++;
                }else{
                    DataService.quizQuestions[i].correct = false;
                }
            }
        }

    }

})();
```

and dataservice.js

```
    (function(){

angular
    .module("MyApp")
    .factory("DataService", DataService);

function DataService(){

    var dataObj = {
        quizQuestions: quizQuestions,
        correctAnswers: correctAnswers
    };
    return dataObj;
}

var correctAnswers = [1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 4, 2, 0, 3];

var quizQuestions  = [
    {
        type: "text",
        text: "How much can a loggerhead weigh?",
        possibilities: [
            {
                answer: "Up to 20kg"
            },
            {
                answer: "Up to 115kg"
            },
            {
                answer: "Up to 220kg"
            },
            {
                answer: "Up to 500kg"
            }
        ],
        selected: null,
        correct: null
    },
    {
        type: "text",
        text: "What is the typical lifespan of a Green Sea Turtle?",
        possibilities: [
            {
                answer: "150 years"
            },
            {
                answer: "10 years"
            },
            {
                answer: "80 years"
            },
            {
                answer: "40 years"
            }
        ],
        selected: null,
        correct: null
    },
    {
        type: "text",
        text: "My Question?",
        possibilities: [
            {
                answer: "Answer1"
            },
            {
                answer: "Answer2 Answer2 Answer2 Answer2 Answer2 Answer2 Answer2 Answer2 Answer2 Answer2 Answer2 Answer2 Answer2 Answer2 Answer2 Answer2 Answer2 Answer2 Answer2 Answer2 Answer2 Answer2 Answer2 Answer2 Answer2 Answer2 Answer2 Answer2 Answer2 Answer2 Answer2 Answer2  "
            },
            {
                answer: "Answer3"
            },
            {
                answer: "Answer4"
            }
        ],
        selected: null,
        correct: null
    },
    {
        type: "text",
        text: "How much can a loggerhead weigh?",
        possibilities: [
            {
                answer: "Up to 20kg"
            },
            {
                answer: "Up to 115kg"
            },
            {
                answer: "Up to 220kg"
            },
            {
                answer: "Up to 500kg"
            }
        ],
        selected: null,
        correct: null
    },
    {
        type: "text",
        text: "This is an Yes/No question?'",
        possibilities: [
            {
                answer: "Yes"
            },
            {
                answer: "No"
            }
        ],
        selected: null,
        correct: null
    },
    {
        type: "text",
        text: "This is five answer choices question ?",
        possibilities: [
            {
                answer: "Loggerhead turtle"
            },
            {
                answer: "Leatherback turtle"
            },
            {
                answer: "Hawksbill Turtle"
            },
            {
                answer: "Alligator Snapping Turtle"
            }
            ,
            {
                answer: "Answer five"
            }
        ],
        selected: null,
        correct: null
    },
    {
        type: "text",
        text: "What is the largest sea turtle on earth?",
        possibilities: [
            {
                answer: "Eastern Snake Necked Turtle"
            },
            {
                answer: "Olive Ridley Sea Turtle"
            },
            {
                answer: "Kemp's Ridley Sea Turtle'"
            },
            {
                answer: "Leatherback"
            }
        ],
        selected: null,
        correct: null
    },
    {
        type: "text",
        text: "How much can a loggerhead weigh?",
        possibilities: [
            {
                answer: "Up to 20kg"
            },
            {
                answer: "Up to 115kg"
            },
            {
                answer: "Up to 220kg"
            },
            {
                answer: "Up to 500kg"
            }
        ],
        selected: null,
        correct: null
    },
    {
        type: "text",
        text: "How Heavy can a leatherback turtle be?",
        possibilities: [
            {
                answer: "900kg"
            },
            {
                answer: "40kg"
            },
            {
                answer: "110kg"
            },
            {
                answer: "300kg"
            }
        ],
        selected: null,
        correct: null
    },
    {
        type: "text",
        text: "Which of these turtles are herbivores?",
        possibilities: [
            {
                answer: "Loggerhead Turtle"
            },
            {
                answer: "Hawksbill Turtle"
            },
            {
                answer: "Leatherback Turtle"
            },
            {
                answer: "Green Turtle"
            }
        ],
        selected: null,
        correct: null
    }
];
})();
```

Comment: did you include the module file in your scripts?

Comment: I think somewhere you have mentioned module as `myApp` but your module declared as `MyApp`. Check all mentions of module name.

Comment: Thank you. I corrected that and now I am getting the error: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: dataserviceProvider

Comment: pls update the question with dataservice.js file

Comment: Thank you I added the dataservice.js

Comment: Same issue as with your module name. `DataService` and `dataservice` are not the same thing!

Comment: @user6934713 the error `Error: [$injector:unpr]` is due to the fact that you haven't declared all of your dependencies. Declare them correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the error you are getting, make sure module/Service/etc naming is correct and dependencies are loaded before they are used:

- Angular modules are case sensitive, so make sure you use same name everywhere, there are some "myApp" and some "MyApp", they are not same
- Make sure dependencies are loaded before you try to inject/use them, for example, if you are trying to inject some service in a Controller, make sure it's loaded before that controller.

Hope this helps.

-Thanks

Comment: Thank you.I tried that. I changed the code above to display the changes:

Answer (score 0):

Module names are case sensitive, in quizMetrics you have myApp instead of MyApp. this will probably solve your problem.

Comment: I corrected that as soon as sajan mentioned it in his comment

Answer (score 0):

When injecting in the controller, use 'DataService' instead of 'dataservice'.